# I'm tryin to replace external website with localhost via modem settings

Tags: networking

I need to replace real external url website with my localhost website like 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.24. I want to do this with my modem settings. I need to manipulate a real domain name is like http://smarttv.website.com/TV with my localhost. If I enter the http://smarttv.website.com/TV website I need to see my localhost website content. How can I do that with my modem settings. Or anybody know any different solution?

Modem : Huawei HG255s
OS    : Windows 10

If I manipulate real domain name I can run my website on TV.

Comment: You are going to get better answers over at https://superuser.com/

Comment: I will try it. Thank you very much.